# Error "Could not find method in a parent or ancestor Context" how do i fix this?

Tags: android, sql, android-intent

i'm trying to send some string from edittext that is located on my first activity into the second activity by pressing Button and i want to see this string in the edittext on that second activity, maybe somebody could help me please

My onClick method:

```
public void calendarOR(View v, AdapterView<?> parent, int position, long id) {
            String data = cala.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), calendar.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",data);
            startActivity(intent);
```

The second activity:

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        userId = extras.getLong("id");
    }
    if (userId > 0) {
        userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + dbelper.TABLE + " where " + dbelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
        userCursor.moveToFirst();
        date.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
        userCursor.close();
    }
```

But i get an Error:

```
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method calendarOR(View) in a parent or 
        ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class 
        com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'buttonCal2'
```

My first activity XML code:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCal2"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:onClick="calendarOR"
    android:text="@string/calendar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.907" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCr"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:onClick="save"
    android:text="@string/create"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.786" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myNoteRab"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cala"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.667" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBCK"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:onClick="back"
    android:text="@string/back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.169" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/deleet"
    android:layout_width="159dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:onClick="delete"
    android:text="@string/delete"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.861"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.786" />
```

Comment: I am not sure because i cant see your xml design, but maybe your buttonCal2 view has the onClick enabled calling the calendarOr method and maybe has a conflict because you are using three params, maybe you need to use only one param view

Comment: now it contains my first activity XML code

Comment: I deleted all the params except "View v" but now it's just do nothing, code working but nothing go to the edittext on my Second Activity, it is still empty...